# Regex ReplaceAll Doesn't Work

Tags: java, android

I copied this code from another StackOverflow post. However, I am having some issues with it. The items matching the pattern specified should be replaced but they are not.

The code is:

```
protected String FixHexValuesInString(String str){
    Log.v(TAG, "before fix: "+ str);
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})").matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int codepoint = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1), 16);
        Log.v(TAG, "matcher group 0: " + matcher.group(0));
        Log.v(TAG, "matcher group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
        str = str.replaceAll(matcher.group(0), String.valueOf((char) codepoint));
    }
    Log.v(TAG, " after fix: "+ str);
    return str;
}
```

Here an example that I wrote to LogCat:

```
before fix: 'id': 1268, 'name': 'Reserva de Usos M\xfaltiples de la Cuenca del Lago de Atitl\xe1n-RUMCLA (Atitl\xe1n Watershed Multiple Use Reserve)'
matcher group 0: \xfa
matcher group 1: fa
matcher group 0: \xe1
matcher group 1: e1
matcher group 0: \xe1
matcher group 1: e1
 after fix: 'id': 1268, 'name': 'Reserva de Usos M\xfaltiples de la Cuenca del Lago de Atitl\xe1n-RUMCLA (Atitl\xe1n Watershed Multiple Use Reserve)'
```

Anybody see why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `String.replaceAll` method at all when you are doing regular expression matching and replacement... You should be using the matchers built in [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`Matcher.appendTail`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29) methods like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "'id': 1268, 'name': 'Reserva de Usos M\\xfaltiples de " +
                 "la Cuenca del Lago de Atitl\\xe1n-RUMCLA (Atitl\\xe1n " +
                 "Watershed Multiple Use Reserve)'";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})").matcher(str);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int codepoint = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1), 16);
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf((char) codepoint));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Output:

```
'id': 1268, 'name': 'Reserva de Usos Múltiples de la Cuenca del Lago de Atitlán-RUMCLA (Atitlán Watershed Multiple Use Reserve)'
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll()` uses the first parameter as regex. In your first group, you have `\xfa` which is an unescaped `\`. Try adding a `\` to the beginning of your group.

Comment: Why replace all occurrences with `replaceAll` for each match?

Comment: Why not? Is there a performance benefit? It looks as if he wants to replace *all* occurrences.

Comment: `"\\x4\\x61 \\x4a"`, with the `replaceAll` method you will get the wrong result (should be `\x4a J` and not `J J`).